# Compile error for a React app: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js)

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs, babel-loader

I am trying to compile a React app. I pulled the repo from Github, did `yarn install` and then compiled it. It gives the following error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js)
SyntaxError: {file_path_here}: Unexpected character ' ​'
```

The the error is in the following file at function `renderItem`

```js
export type DisplayItemT = {
    mainText: string;
    secondaryText: string[];
};


function renderItemsAsCards(items, options): string {
    let cardsrows_mso = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; ) {
        let cards = '';
        const record = items[i];
        const item={mainText: record.get('name'),secondaryText: [record.get('department'), record.get('location')]};
        const card = renderItem(item);

        cards = cards.concat(card);
        i++;
        if( i === items.length) {
            break;
        }

        cardsrows_mso = cards ? cardsrows_mso.concat(cards): ``;
        
    }

    return cardsrows_mso ? `
    <table width="100%" border="0" style="text-align: ${options.align || 'left'};">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                ${cardsrows_mso}
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    `
    :``;
}

function renderItem(item​​​​​​​: DisplayItemT): string {
    return `<td style="height: 100%; padding: 5px; width: 202px; max-width: 320px; min-width: 202px; display: inline-block;">
                <div style="width: 100%; padding: 15px 0px 20px; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #cccccc; border-radius: 5px; height: 100%">
                    <h6 style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 500; color: #333; line-height: 19px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; margin: 0;">${item.mainText}</h6>
                    <p style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 17px; color: #999; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">${item.secondaryText[0]}</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 17px; color: #999; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">${item.secondaryText[1]}</p>
                </div>
            </td>`;
}
```

I get the above mention error, and the location of error is in the line `function renderItem(item​​​​​​​: DisplayItemT): string {` at the end of parameter `item` in the above line. It says there's an unexpected character `' ​'` but I can't find any extra blank spaces anywhere.

Also the function `renderItem` is separated because it needs to be used in other files. But if I put the string code from that function inside `renderItemsAsCards` (which calls 'renderItem') the code compiles fine.

My package.json, webpack.config.js files are pretty huge. So if I should post something from them please let me know. I would appreciate any help with this

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I've faced This Issue
is because I've added/removed a package or component,
Firstly you should try and install the package separately,
coz' sometimes the package is not installed by using yarn/npm install.
And this might get fixed by restarting the server/APP
or
alternatively, you can also try to change the browser tab or restart the browser.
If not then kindly share the last file you've made change in the error is mostly due to the change in some component

Comment: I've tried restarting the server multiple times. So initially there was just 1 function and in the end I returned a string. The code from `renderItem` was inside `renderItemsAsCards`, i.e. instead of `const card = renderItem(item);` I had const card = `<td style="height: 100%; padding:.......` And this compiled just fine. when I made it into 2 function it started throwing that error